# legal term explanation required

Tags: employment, non-compete, uae

According to below mentioned clause ,Am I allowed to join other IT company in the practice **Computer Software House** or not

> "To refrain from directly or indirectly competing with 
>       the Employer or working for another competing organisation 
>       in the practice of **Computer Software House** 
>       within UAE for a period of 24 months 
>       (not exceeding 24 calendar months) following the expiration or
>        termination of the Employment Contract."

Answer (score 2):

Anti-competition clauses are legal under UAE law, see [here](http://www.mondaq.com/x/583466/Contract+of+Employment/PostContractual+NonCompetition+Clause+according+to+the+Laws+of+the+United+Arab+Emirates) and [here](https://www.thenational.ae/business/uae-non-competition-clauses-in-employment-contracts-have-legal-limitations-1.161780). [Article 127 of UAE Labour Law](https://www.moid.gov.ae/Laws/UAE_Labour_Law.pdf) specifically allows non-compete clauses related to access to clients of business secrets, provided that

> the agreement must be confined, in terms of time, place and the 
>   nature of the business, to the extent necessary to safeguard the
>   employer's legitimate  interests.

which means there is no fixed upper duration of the restriction. [This article](http://lexarabiae.meyer-reumann.com/issues/2016-2/vol-xx-issue-2-apr-2016-articles/enforceability-of-non-competition-clauses-under-uae-law/) analyzes some of the nuances of UAE law on this point, and they observe

> Concerning the timely limitation, a reasonable duration for a
>   non-competition clause normally ranges between 3 months to 2 years
>   from the date of termination of the employment contract. In the past,
>   it was often held that the (previous) automatic employment ban of 6
>   months after termination have a similar effect as a non-competition
>   clause i.e. preventing the employee to enter the country during this
>   time; hence, it was concluded that a specific non-competition clauses
>   included in the employment agreement should only be limited to 6
>   months as well.

Under a ruling by the Dubai Court of Cassation, Petition NO. 58/2008 (as summarized in the preceding analysis), violating a non-compete clause with a duration of 2 years can be enforced, but the onus is on the employer (plaintiff) to prove that they have suffered the alleged damage.

Answer (score -2):

**No**

It means what it says, however, restraint of trade clauses are often subject to a test of reasonableness given that they affect a person's ability to make a living, I am not familiar at all with UAE law to know if this is applicable. I can say that 24 months across all industries would be unenforceable in Australia.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: I did not understand ? Can i join other IT company which dont have direct relation with thier client and also not in same domain .

Comment: @rajpawar "no" is difficult to understand?

Comment: It doesn't make any sense to offer a definitive, unqualified, answer (**No**) and then say you don't know anything about the laws of polity in question. That makes it difficult to understand.